# Laravel 4 Custom Validation Rule issue

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a custom validation rule in Laravel 4. I have tried registering the custom validation rule in the model, and also the start/global.php.

Here's my code for registering a new validation rule:

```
Validator::register('validate_login', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    $password = Input::get('password');
    $accountcount = DB::table('account')->where('account_email', '=', $value)->where('password','=',password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    if ($accountcount!=1) return false;
    return true;
});
```

As soon as I try to do things, I get this :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Factory::add_rule()

Is there anything else I need to do? Can someone please look into it and help me? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the `Validator::register` is no more in use and doesn't work.

Instead, `Validator::extend` will do the job.

Thanks!